# how to increment cells dynamically with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to develop a reusable List to excel method. Using this example, "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx"

I see the cells are being referenced individually like so,

```
workSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "ID Number";
```

I want to be able to auto fill the column names, and also each cell from left to right dynamically. I would imagine there is a better way than having to type out "A", "B"....."A1"  etc into the workSheet.Cells[] directly or even a better way than storing the alphabet into a list.

Here is what I have so far,

```
public static void DownloadExcelFile<T>(List<T> list, string fileName)
{
    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

    // Make the object visible.
    excelApp.Visible = true;

    excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

    Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;

    //create column headings
    foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor descriptor in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(list))
    {
        //how can I reference workSheet.Cells by row, and have the 
        //column incremented somehow within the loop?
        workSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = descriptor.name;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ordinal number instead of the letter code:

```
int colIndex = 1;
foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor descriptor in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(list))
{
    workSheet.Cells[1, colIndex++] = descriptor.Name;
}
```

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks! I figured it was something simple like that, but I was confusing myself while reviewing a range and thought I needed to use that maybe instead.  I haven't worked with this library in a long while, so I am basically relearning it again.